# How to determine tab order in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

What determines the user tabbing order in shiny? (Where the cursor goes in the input fields on each tab press).

I've looked for documentation on this but can't find anything.

Comment: This might help [How and when to use the tabindex attribute](https://bitsofco.de/how-and-when-to-use-the-tabindex-attribute/); TLDR: *"The order in which these elements are placed in the source HTML document controls the order in which they become focusable when navigating with a keyboard"*